# how to combine datasets having common variables?

Tags: sas

I have two datasets, say, A & B and they share common variables. I need to merge A & B by the common variables. Please suggest me how should I do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an entry level question, you would have found the answer simply searching on google.
Anyway, you can use the merge statement, please remember to:
1) do a prior sort by the variables you will use as merge key to each dataset and 
2) please, remember that both datasets should have the same name, nature, and length for the variables you will use as merge key.
3) Also remember that if in both datasets there are variables with the same name, but these won't be used as merge keys, in the output dataset there will be the variable from only one dataset, rename one of them if it's your case.

the code will be

```
proc sort data=A; by mergekey1 mergekey2; run; /*sorting A dataset by mergekeys, please add merge key to the list*/
proc sort data=B; by mergekey1 mergekey2; run;  /*same for B dataset*/

data want;

merge A B;
by mergekey1 mergekey2;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

you really should provide a little more information like what the record layout is of each table and what you want to end up with as well as what you've already tried.  That said you could use proc sql as follows:

```
proc sql;
     create table new_data as
            select a.*,b.*
                   from table1 as a
            inner join
                        table2 as b
            on a.common_var = b.common_var;
            quit;
```

note that if a and b have common named variables the ones in table1 will be over written.  if you want to keep both sets of variables you would need to do:

```
select a.*,b.var1 as bvar1,b.var2 as bvar2 ....
```

This answer assumes that you have a variable you can merge on.  If you don't you may want to look at proc merge.